# Handle NoSuchKey error with Custom Storage class AWS S3 and Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using Django, I wanted to handle the NoSuchKey error which happens when am redirected to the file link from my Django project.

How best can I use the Custom storage error to handle this :

```
"""Custom storage settings."""
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from botocore.exceptions import NoSuchKey
from django.shortcuts import render


    class FileStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
        """File storage class."""
        print(" Hi there am AWS")
        def open(self, name, mode='rb'):
            try:
                return super().open(name, mode)
            except NoSuchKey:
                return {'errror': 'Error Happened'}
```

I already defined the class in the settings.py as below :

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'proj.storage.FileStorage'
```

Remember when you define the following env variables, you can auto upload files to the specific Images or File fields in the Models, now I want a centralized way of handling the `NoSuchKey` error and I show a custom page or template

```
AWS_LOCATION = ENV.str('AWS_LOCATION', default='')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ENV.str('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', default='')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ENV.str('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', default='')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = ENV.str('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME', default='')
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = ENV.str('AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION', default='')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = ENV.bool('AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE', default=False)
```

How can I do this ?

Here's the error I get :

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
files/file-information.html
</Key>
<RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>
yOjP+w8917JsB08ZV2Gf+WMUDfIETFZcVvn/fxxxxxxp0PWhi0nIss7qfLaM4gizdWfX1k4vhalE0XMOg=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: You have a try/except block, so it seems you are already "handling" the error.  What is your actual question?

Comment: @JohnGordon, its not handling it yet, my question is I tried and failed, the error still ocurrs.

Comment: What do you mean "the error still occurs"?  I don't see how that is possible, since you have a try/except block.  Please show us the actual full error traceback message.

Comment: Its possible because when I click on the generated link from S3, it shows the NoSuchKey error. If you know what happens when you upload a file let's say via Django admin, thats what happen, you get a generated link, so I want to handle this link with a custom page

Comment: I already asked you to show us the full error traceback message.  If you're not willing to do that, there's nothing more I can do to help.  Good luck.

Comment: If the `NoSuchKey` error shows up in the error output, then it looks like your try/except isn't actually being called.  Please show us the view code.

Comment: Also, the error message shows `files/-information.html` as the key.  Is that correct?  It feels like there should be some other word before the dash.

Comment: I have corrected the file name, it was a typo, then for the part where I get this, its on the return value in JSON (its a url), it has a link generated from S3 , the file is not on AWS but this error is thrown. Hope this information provides more context

Comment: Please show us the view code, as I already asked.